# Not contained in aggregate or group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Here is the table:**

Product(maker, model, type)

The table "Product" includes information about the maker, model number, and type ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer')

**Challenge:**

Find out makers who produce only the models of the same type, and the number of those models exceeds 1.

**What I did:**

```
SELECT maker, type
FROM Product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT (type) > 1 AND COUNT( DISTINCT type ) = 1
```

**Problem:**

*Column 'Product.type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

**Notes:**

In the table, the maker D creates only Printers. So, I want to get:

```
Maker | Type

D     | Printer
```

If I remove type from the query I get D, which is what I want, but without type. If I include type in GROUP BY clause I get different result.

**Question:**

How to fix this?

Comment: Your error string is not MySQL but SQL Server. Actually, your query would work and produce correct results in MySQL.

Comment: my pleasure. Please note that this site is English speakers oriented, foreign language phrases might confuse the non-speakers.

Comment: got you...note taken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  maker, MIN(type)
FROM    product
GROUP BY
        maker
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1
        AND COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: It works) perfect) one more question if you dont mind: why should MIN be used? even for varchar types?

Comment: @Joe: because you need an aggregate function over an expression which is not in `GROUP BY`. You can use `MAX` if you like it more.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT maker, type
FROM Product
GROUP BY maker,Type
HAVING COUNT (type) > 1 AND COUNT( DISTINCT type ) = 1
```